# Oracle ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1

Tags: oracle, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

For special needs, I use the unzipped jar format ojdbc6.jar.

The code source of my connection to the database oracle is :

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
....

    try
    {

      String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
      String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@x.x.x.x:1521:dev";
      String login = "dev";
      String password = "dev";

      Class.forName(driver);

      DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password); // Error is generated by this line

    }
    catch (SQLException e)
    {

      System.err.println("error");

    }

    .....
```

When i launch the program, i have this exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.setSessionFields(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:999)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.<init>(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:235)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:370)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
.......
```

I use

- ojdbc6.jar (11.2.0.2)
- JRE 1.6.0_24
- Oracle 11g
- The database is accessible and the data connection are correct.

Comment: what is the name of the oracle instance? Also check the output of "lsnrctl services"

Comment: the name of instance is dev. the connexion is ok with an other program.

Comment: that does not prove that you will use the same instance. how about providing the output of lsnrctl.

Comment: I use the same code in a simple program and it works!

Comment: Have you solved this problem somehow? I seem to facing the same problem after re-packaging the oracle driver jar for special purposes.

Comment: @benjamin No, not yet

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the same error above for a RMI server issue. I added  `-Djava.security.policy=$RMIPATH"/policy.txt"` to my runtime script and created a policy.txt file that stated.

```
grant {
 permission java.security.AllPermission;
};
```

I hate disabling security but it works... My runtime is 1.8.31